# how css apply red in calendar when the time is unvailable

Tags: css, angular, angular-ng-if

I would like show unavailable time in apply background red, this is a picture to
explain what I would like to do

[image]

I have hours of work, for example 8H to 17H,
if one of the hours is unavailable I would like to apply red color, how I can do that ?
I think to save my date "heure" to Array JSON ? or directly JSON ?
This is how I tried

```js
  constructor(private _calendar: CalendarModel) {
    let plageJour = this.trancheFin - this.trancheDeb;

    for (let i = 0; i < plageJour; i++) {
      this.libelleTranche.push({"heure":"i + this.trancheDeb","unvailable":true});
    }

  }
```

And if the hour is unavailble I apply

```js
    <a *ngIf="???" [ngStyle]="{background:invailable}">
        {{ heure }}H-{{heure+1}}H
    </a>
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarModel } from '../calendar-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heure',
  templateUrl: './heure.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heure.component.css']
})
export class HeureComponent implements OnInit {

  invailable="red";
  trancheDeb: number = 8;
  trancheFin: number = 17;
  dateNow0: number;//le début du jour d'aujourdh'ui à 00H en timestamp

  libelleTranche = new Array(); //calculé fin de tranche - debut de tranche

  constructor(private _calendar: CalendarModel) {
    let plageJour = this.trancheFin - this.trancheDeb;

    for (let i = 0; i < plageJour; i++) {
      this.libelleTranche.push(i + this.trancheDeb);
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thinking is correct, but there are a few wrong things :

- in your template, you wrote `inavailable` instead of `heure.unavailable`
- `{"heure":"i + this.trancheDeb"}` should be `{"heure": i + this.trancheDeb}`
- `{ background : heure.unavailable }` will just yield `{ background : true }` or `{ background : false }` which won't do anything.

Instead, set a class :

```
<a [class.red]="heure.unavailable">
```

Alternatively :

```
<a [ngClass]="{ red : heure.unavailable }">
```

and in the CSS :

```
a.red{
  background-color : red;
}
```

Comment: There's also some mistakes in the code, like `"heure":"i + this.trancheDeb"`. Your solution is correct, just wanted to mention that it might not work due to other mistakes made in the code.

Answer (score 0):

this is my new snippet

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarModel } from '../calendar-model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heure',
  templateUrl: './heure.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heure.component.css']
})
export class HeureComponent implements OnInit {

  trancheDeb: number = 8;
  trancheFin: number = 17;
  dateNow0: number;//le début du jour d'aujourdh'ui à 00H en timestamp

  libelleTranche = new Array(); //calculé fin de tranche - debut de tranche

  constructor(private _calendar: CalendarModel) {
    let plageJour = this.trancheFin - this.trancheDeb;

    for (let i = 0; i < plageJour; i++) {
      this.libelleTranche.push({
        "afficheH":i + this.trancheDeb,
        "unavailable":this.isDayReserver(this.dateNow0+this.trancheDeb,this.trancheDeb+1*60*60)
      });
    }
    console.log(this.libelleTranche);

  }
```

I release with exemple to

```js
<ul >
    <li 
    class="heure" 
    *ngFor="let heure of libelleTranche" 
    [ngClass]="{ odd: (heure%2 == 0), even: heure %2 == 1 } ">
    <a [ngClass]="{ red : heure.unavailable }">
        {{ heure.afficheH }} 
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
```